# Как сохранить изменения в дата сете в одну матрицу используя scipy.sparse.hstack в python?

Tags: python, text, матрицы, анализ

У меня задание провести линейную регрессию и сделать прогноз оклада по описанию вакансии. Вот как я это делал:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Location = r'C:\Users\803008\Desktop\salary-train.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location)
```

Загрузил данные:

```
                                 FullDescription LocationNormalized  \
    0      International Sales Manager London ****k  ****...             London   
    1      An ideal opportunity for an individual that ha...             London   
    2      Online Content and Brand Manager// Luxury Reta...  South East London   
    3      A great local marketleader is seeking a perman...            Dereham   
    4      Registered Nurse / RGN  Nursing Home for Young...   Sutton Coldfield   
    5      Sales and Marketing Assistant will provide adm...            Crawley   
    6      Vacancy Ladieswear fashion Area Manager / Regi...                 UK 
    ContractTime  SalaryNormalized  
    0        permanent             33000  
    1        permanent             50000  
    2        permanent             40000  
    3        permanent             22500  
    4              nan             20355  
    5              nan             22500  
    6        permanent             32000
```

Привел их к нижнему шрифту

```
df['FullDescription'].str.lower()
train1=df['FullDescription'].str.lower()
train2=train1.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', regex = True)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

Я оставил только те слова которые встречаются минимум в 5 объектах:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.05)
train3 = vectorizer.fit_transform(train2)
```

Заменил пропуски в столбцах LocationNormalized и ContractTime на строку 'nan'

```
LocTrain =df['LocationNormalized'].fillna('nan', inplace=True)
ContrTime = df['ContractTime'].fillna('nan', inplace=True)
```

Потом необходимо было получить one-hot-кодирование признаков LocationNormalized и ContractTime

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
enc = DictVectorizer()
X_train = enc.fit_transform(df[['LocationNormalized',   'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
```

Но я не знаю как объединить все полученные признаки в одну матрицу "объекты-признаки" по заданию нужно использовать команду scipy.sparse.hstack. Как заменить с дата сете столбцы на те которые я уже преобразовал(изменил размер шрифта, заменил разделители на пробелы) и сгруппировать всё в одну матрицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо сохранить все изменения в изменяемую переменную или дата сет.
Например:

```
df['FullDescription'] = df['FullDescription'].str.lower()
```

а потом применять команду `scipy.sparse.hstack` или `enc.fit_transform`